# Stylesheet not found when link is correct

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, slim

I am trying to link my stylesheet to my php template for my website. I used the link:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{app.request.basepath }}/App/views/templates/style.css">`

Now, this works on my localhost server(I use MAMP), but when i upload the files to the web host I get the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

The panel I have only seems to support up to 5.5, where as I use 5.6 on the local server. Could also be the issue.

And it also gives me a link, which is the exact link to the file, no misspelled or capitalized letters. The file I am trying to link the stylesheet to is in the same folder as the stylesheet. I am also rewriting the .htaccess file because I am using SlimPHP the file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I think that this might have something to do with it being unable to link but i am not fully sure. Thanks in advance for all of your help

**Edit:
    I fixed my problem by linking my style sheet to the public file in my directory. From there, I could link any images by using CSS, but also I had to place them in the public directory**

Comment: Did you try to see you styles in browser? In browser line $my_domain_or_localhost/App/views/templates/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I route theme-specific stylesheets in Slim and Twig.  First I create a new config variable, `themes.path`, that contains the actual filesystem path to my theme.  Then I set up a route for `css/theme.css`:

```
$app->config([
    'themes.path'    =>  "path/to/themes"
]);

/* Render theme CSS */
$app->get('/css/theme.css', function () use ($app) {
    $app->response->headers->set("Content-Type", "text/css");
    $css_include = $app->config('themes.path') . "/myTheme/css/theme.css";
    $app->response->setBody(file_get_contents($css_include));
}
```

To use the theme stylesheet in my template documents, I simply do:

```
<!-- Theme stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.uri.css}}theme.css" type="text/css" >
```

Where `site.uri.css` is a global template variable that contains the path to my (public) css directory.  You can hardcode that part, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

It was better to give us the online address.

But now you should check the converted address in your html codes.

You should press Ctrl+U in "Firefox" OR right click->View Page Source.

Then search for `/App/views/templates/style.css">` then check the full address and change your main code !

Answer (score 0):

Give 0777 Or 0755 permission to `style.css`  file for access